# Show how often each word from a list appears in a dataframe (text) or dfm

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a list of words and I would like to count, how often each of those words appears in a dataframe with text data or a dfm. What I have made sofar:

My list:

```
words <- dictionary(list(words = c("House", "Mountain", "Blue", "Night")))
```

My dataframe (have also a dfm from title and text):

| id | title | date | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blablabla | 22.07.2023 | blablablabla Blue blablabla |
| 2 | blablabla | 23.06.2023 | bala Blue blabla Blue blabla Blue |

The output should be:

| id | title | date | text | word | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blablabla | 22.07.2023 | blablablabla Blue blablabla | Blue | 1 |
| 2 | blablabla | 23.06.2023 | bala Blue blabla Blue blabla Blue | Blue | 3 |

Comment: What is `dictionary(.)`?

Comment: I fixed the data inconsistency in your example. What happens if one string includes more than one from `words`? For instance, if `$text[1]` were instead `"blablablabla Blue Mountain Night blablabla"`, what should the corresponding `word` and `count` values be? Are you expecting list-columns, row-repeating, string-compaction, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a slight edit to the input data to show a case where more than one of the word from the `words` vector exists in the `text` column.

I handle that with a loop and braking those into multiple rows. However, we can also summarize those, for instance into a list and add the `count` together: `summarise(word = list(word), count = sum(count), .by = c(title, date, text))`

```r
read.table(text= "title     date    text
blablabla   22.07.2023  'blablablabla Blue blablabla'
blablabla   23.06.2023  'bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue'", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactor = F) -> df1

words <- c("House", "Mountain", "Blue", "Night")
```

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

map_dfr(words, ~ df1 %>%  mutate(word = if_else(str_detect(text, .x), .x, NA))) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(count = str_count(text, word))
```

```
#>       title       date                             text  word count
#> 5 blablabla 22.07.2023      blablablabla Blue blablabla  Blue     1
#> 6 blablabla 23.06.2023 bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue  Blue     3
#> 8 blablabla 23.06.2023 bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue Night     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Strangely the function ```if_else()``` didn't detect my text data as ```string```. I had to change the ```if_else()``` that only accepts character vectors, function into an ```ifelse()```  function that accepts also vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the `words` and count them summarily, that will do:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(
    # count number of keywords:
    count = str_count(text, str_c(words, collapse = "|")),
    # extract instances of keywords:
    keyword = str_extract_all(text, 
                                   str_c("(?i)\\b(", str_c(words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
  ))
      title       date                                  text count                      keyword
1 blablabla 22.07.2023           blablablabla Blue blablabla     1                         Blue
2 blablabla 23.06.2023      bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue     4      Blue, Blue, Night, Blue
3 blablabla 23.08.2023 bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue     4 Mountain, House, Night, Blue
```

**EDIT**:

It's quite a different task if you want to count the `words` not summarily but by type. This could be done like so (see [Count number of keywords each in their own column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257798/count-number-of-keywords-each-in-their-own-column/76257863#76257863)):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(tokens = strsplit(text, " ")) %>%
    unnest(tokens) %>%
    filter(tokens %in% words) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = tokens,
        values_from = tokens,
        values_fn = length,
        values_fill = 0
    ) %>%
    left_join(df)
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  title     date       text                                   Blue Night Mountain House
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>                                 <int> <int>    <int> <int>
1 blablabla 22.07.2023 blablablabla Blue blablabla               1     0        0     0
2 blablabla 23.06.2023 bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue          3     1        0     0
3 blablabla 23.08.2023 bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue     1     1        1     1
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text= "title     date    text
blablabla   22.07.2023  'blablablabla Blue blablabla'
blablabla   23.06.2023  'bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue'
blablabla   23.08.2023  'bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue'", 
header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)
  
words <- c("House", "Mountain", "Blue", "Night")
```