# Count number of keywords each in their own column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Let's say I have data like this:

```
df <-  read.table(text= "title     date    text
blablabla   22.07.2023  'blablablabla Blue blablabla'
blablabla   23.06.2023  'bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue'
blablabla   23.08.2023  'bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue'", 
header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)
```

and a vector with `words` that I consider keywords:

```
words <- c("House", "Mountain", "Blue", "Night")
```

What I want to achieve is count the number of times the `words` occur in `df$text` but **count each type of `word` separately in its own column**. I have this code so far:

```
llibrary(tidyverse)
df %>%
  # extract instances of keywords:
  mutate(
    keyword = str_extract_all(text, 
                              str_c("(?i)\\b(", str_c(words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
  )) %>%
  # turn into alternation pattern:
  mutate(keyword = lapply(keyword, function(x) str_c(x, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  # create row ID:
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  # separate into rows splitting by `|`:
  separate_rows(keyword, sep = '\\|') %>% 
  # cast each keyword in its own row:
  pivot_wider(names_from = keyword, values_from = keyword, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0
              ) %>%
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  title     date       text                                   Blue Night Mountain House
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>                                 <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 blablabla 22.07.2023 blablablabla Blue blablabla               1     0        0     0
2 blablabla 23.06.2023 bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue          1     1        0     0
3 blablabla 23.08.2023 bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue     1     1        1     1
```

That's not what I want because the `function(x) 1` part does not sum up but merely registers whether a `word` is present or not. How does this have to be changed to get me this output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  title     date       text                                   Blue Night Mountain House
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>                                 <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 blablabla 22.07.2023 blablablabla Blue blablabla               1     0        0     0
2 blablabla 23.06.2023 bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue          3     1        0     0
3 blablabla 23.08.2023 bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue     1     1        1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df %>%
    mutate(tokens = strsplit(text, " ")) %>%
    unnest(tokens) %>%
    filter(tokens %in% words) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = tokens,
        values_from = tokens,
        values_fn = length,
        values_fill = 0
    ) %>%
    left_join(df)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  title     date       text                            Blue Night Mountain House
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>                          <int> <int>    <int> <int>
1 blablabla 22.07.2023 blablablabla Blue blablabla        1     0        0     0
2 blablabla 23.06.2023 bala Blue blabla Blue Night B…     3     1        0     0
3 blablabla 23.08.2023 bala Mountain blabla House Ni…     1     1        1     1
```

Comment: That's an absolutely marvelous solution - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative, *split* on space, set *factor* levels, get frequency *table*:

```
cbind(df[ "text" ],
      t(sapply(strsplit(df$text, " ", fixed = TRUE), 
               function(i) table(factor(i, levels = words))))
      )
#                                    text House Mountain Blue Night
# 1           blablablabla Blue blablabla     0        0    1     0
# 2      bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue     0        0    3     1
# 3 bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue     1        1    1     1
```

---

Or to fix your solution, use *length*:

```
#...
pivot_wider(names_from = keyword, values_from = keyword, 
            values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
#...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative with `data.table` and `stringr`.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
for(word in words){
  set(setDT(df), j=word, value = str_count(df$text, word))
}
```

**output**

```
       title       date                                  text House Mountain  Blue Night
      <char>     <char>                                <char> <int>    <int> <int> <int>
1: blablabla 22.07.2023           blablablabla Blue blablabla     0        0     1     0
2: blablabla 23.06.2023      bala Blue blabla Blue Night Blue     0        0     3     1
3: blablabla 23.08.2023 bala Mountain blabla House Night Blue     1        1     1     1
```